# Retirar NA de um csv no R

Tags: r, csv

Bom dia, pessoal! Estou tentando retirar `NA` de uns dados para um relatório porém o código está retornando `null`.
Segue abaixo o meu código:

Obs: No caso eu preciso deixar apenas as colunas `Population` e `Area (sq. mi.)`.

```
rm(list=ls())

dados<-read.csv(file = "C:/Users/lucas/Downloads/projeto/dados_corrigido.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ";",dec = ".",na.strings = "NA")
dados1 <- na.omit(dados[,2:3]) 
str(dados)

# Inicio ------------------------------------------------------------------

summary(dados)
# Country              X.Population.       X.Area..sq..mi...  X.Infant.mortality..per.1000.births.. X.GDP....per.capita.. X.Literacy.....
# Afghanistan   :  1   Min.   :7.026e+03   Min.   :       2   Min.   :  2.29                        Min.   :  500         Min.   : 17.60
# Albania       :  1   1st Qu.:4.376e+05   1st Qu.:    4648   1st Qu.:  8.15                        1st Qu.: 1900         1st Qu.: 70.60
# Algeria       :  1   Median :4.787e+06   Median :   86600   Median : 21.00                        Median : 5550         Median : 92.50
# American Samoa:  1   Mean   :2.874e+07   Mean   :  598227   Mean   : 35.51                        Mean   : 9690         Mean   : 82.84
# Andorra       :  1   3rd Qu.:1.750e+07   3rd Qu.:  441811   3rd Qu.: 55.70                        3rd Qu.:15700         3rd Qu.: 98.00
# Angola        :  1   Max.   :1.314e+09   Max.   :17075200   Max.   :191.19                        Max.   :55100         Max.   :100.00
# (Other)       :221                                          NA's   :3                             NA's   :1             NA's   :18
#   X.Birthrate.    X.Deathrate.    X.Agriculture.       X.Continent.    X.
#  Min.   : 7.29   Min.   : 2.290   Min.   :  0.000   "AFRICA" :57    Mode:logical
#  1st Qu.:12.67   1st Qu.: 5.910   1st Qu.:  0.415   "AMERICA":50    NA's:227
# Median :18.79   Median : 7.840   Median : 54.000   "ASIA"   :56
# Mean   :22.11   Mean   : 9.241   Mean   :103.015   "EUROPE" :43
# 3rd Qu.:29.82   3rd Qu.:10.605   3rd Qu.:163.500   "OCEANIA":21
# Max.   :50.73   Max.   :29.740   Max.   :769.000
# NA's   :3       NA's   :4        NA's   :15
```

Dados: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRuX54rw5NBrxlNcXGR7Kx1TAZ6U3hPu/view

Comment: Por favor, disponibilize seus dados para que possa receber ajuda. Da forma que colocou em seu código, seu arquivo ```csv``` está em sua pasta Downloads, portanto, não temos como replicá-los. Use ```dput(dados)``` para isso.

Comment: Bom dia: Aqui está o meu banco: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRuX54rw5NBrxlNcXGR7Kx1TAZ6U3hPu/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Você precisa disponibilizar publicamente, não consigo acessar os dados através do seu link.

Comment: perdão. o arquivo já está publico.

Comment: Seus dados não possuem nenhum ```NA``` nas colunas ```População``` e ```Área```.

Comment: então, acredito qeu fiz uma confusão. e tenha que apenas isolar  as colunas População e Área para realizar a Estatística Descritiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de selecionar as colunas desejadas. Utilizarei dois exemplos, através do pacote `dplyr` e pelo `R base`.

Pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_csv("~/Downloads/dados_corrigido.csv") %>%
  select(Country, `"Population"`, `"Area (sq. mi.)"`)

summary(dados)
```

Pelo `R base`:

```
library(readr)

dados <- read_csv("~/Downloads/dados_corrigido.csv") 
dados <- dados[,1:3]

summary(dados)
```

Obs.: Utilizei o pacote `readr` para fazer uma melhor leitura do `csv`.

Answer (score -1):

você já tentou o drop_NA do pacote tidyr?
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA), y = c("a", NA, "b"))
df %>% drop_na()